# Magento2 : Call custom Js before body closing tag on every page

Tags: javascript, magento2.2.3

I have used the below code to call example js file which is located in `Magento_Theme` folder of the theme.

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="exampleScript">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="Magento_Theme::js/example.js"></script>]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

But this gives `404-Error` as it goes to find from [URL](https://www.example.com/Magento_Theme::js/example.js) from where

> /pub/static/version1564550212/frontend/Themevendor/Themename/nl_NL/Magento_Theme/js

path is missing.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Yes Js is now loaded, but my main purpose was to load after all js is merged, Using this code it gives me error $ is not defined. any idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following way....

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="exampleScript">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="js/example.js"></script>]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```